# Why is "MC" greater than "MU" when I use the jstat command?

Tags: java, jstat

Why is MC greater than mu when I use the jstat command?, eg.

```
$./jstat -gc 2820
 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       MC     MU    CCSC   CCSU   YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
174720.0 174720.0  0.0   64633.5 1747712.0 1449365.0 2097152.0   263408.2  304768.0 299380.5 37760.0 36489.7     13    1.766   0      0.000    1.766
```

[image]

It says that `MC` is `304768.0` while `MU` is `299380.5`.

Comment: Why is this surprising you? Have you checked the documentation to understand what `MC` and `MU` means? This observation sounds very straightforward and totally normal to me.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/specs/man/jstat.html) says that

- MC: Metaspace **capacity** (kB).
- MU: Metacspace **utilization** (kB).

So `MC` is the total capacity and `MU` is how much of `MC` you are currently using. Hence it only makes sense that `MC` is greater (equals) `MU`.

The opposite would be weird, but not `MC > MU`.

---

In your case you have a metaspace capacity of around **304 MB** and currently use **299 MB** of that.

Answer (score 0):

1. MC is Metaspace  size
2. MU is Metaspace  used size